# is there a way to make this code work without removing the Positioned.fill widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to build a listview of clickable images that scrolls horizontally so i put the listview within a container and every child of the list view is a container that has a stack containing the image and and an inkwell widget, this code is throwing an error when building the stack, i tried to play with the code adding height or width to the containers, also tried removing cliprrect widget but it only works fine when i remove the positioned.fill widget around the image.

```
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: 150,
        child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: [
            // image container
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Positioned.fill(
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                      child: CachedNetworkImage(
                        placeholder: (context, url) =>
                            Image.asset('assets/images/def3.png'),
                        errorWidget: (context, posterUrl, error) =>
                            Image.asset('assets/images/def3.png'),
                        imageUrl: 'imageurl',
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned.fill(
                    child: Material(
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      child: InkWell(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        onTap: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[Failed assertion: line 588 pos 12: 'size.isFinite': is not true.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HANiO.png)

[When the exception is thrown this was the stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7Wbo.png)

Comment: What is the reason for the stack structure? Why not wrap your Container with the Inkwell?

Comment: @Wessel
When Wrapping my container with inkwell the splash highlight appears behind the image and i found that this happens because the inkwell widget shows the highlight on the first material ancestor to it in the tree so there must be a material between the image and the inkwell in order to show the highlight on top of the image

Comment: i added a width to the Container which is parent of the stack and it now works as expected but i don't know why, i even think i tried this before but it was not working.